# Closing dialog box automatically while running a batch script

Tags: java, eclipse, svn

I made a batch script that automates the checkout of projects from svn and imports them to the eclipse workspace by itself. However, I get a dialog box from eclipse saying "an error has occurred. Please check logs in .metdata for more info" . 
This usually happens when the project is already imported in eclipse. (or if the .project file is missing).

My main concern is , how can I automate the closing of this dialog box ?

part of code below:

```
if /i !choice!==1 (
cls
echo %NL% Project List %NL%
echo %NL%=================================================%NL%
type project_list.txt

    For /F "tokens=1" %%i IN (project_list.txt) DO (
    %svnbin% checkout checkout_location checked_out_location  --username %userid%  --password  %password% 
    %javaloc%/eclipse.exe -nosplash -application test.myapp.App -data  workspace_location -import  project_name 
    )
    goto :end
    )
```

**test.myapp.App** is a java application file by Spektom. It automates the import of java projects to eclipse.

Will appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: It would be better to look at the errors. It is possible that the workspace could be damaged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Batch is simply a way of automating simple shell processes.  It has no way to interact with graphical dialog boxes.  To do that, you'll need a more powerful language (such as [AutoIt](http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/)).

The better solution would be to investigate and eliminate the error instead of just dismissing it.  The dialog is indicating some sort of problem that won't be fixed by closing the box.  Check your log files and see if there's anything useful in there.  I suspect that this is probably caused by something in the java application that you are running.  If you are running [the program](https://github.com/spektom/eclipse-import) that I think you're running, then you may be dealing with a problem due to using an unsupported version of Eclipse.  That utility hasn't been substantially updated in several years, so it may not work with the latest Eclipse versions.